# How to avoid merge commits using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

The problem is when I'm **pull** and **push** to the remote repository, it generates a extra commit under my name.  The commit says

**Merge branch 'master' of ssh://....**

I found answers says I should use a command **git pull --rebase** in git bash to avoid this commit.

But I'm commonly using TortoiseGit. So how can I do it properly with TortoiseGit?

Comment: ^^^ hardly a useful comment.  Tortoise Git is fine for most standard SCM operations on top of Git, including SVN dcommits.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is an option since version 1.8 of Tortoise Git.  The rebase option can be invoked from a the Fetch command:

[image: TortoiseGit fetch dialog highlighting Launch-Rebase-After-Fetch checkbox]

Comment: TortoiseGit always launch rebase window when checking this option, even if it is a fast forward. Is it possible to launch rebase window ONLY if pull is not fast forward ?

Answer (score 15):

Starting with TortoiseGit 2.0 you can set `pull.rebase` to `true` in git config (e.g., by issuing `git config pull.rebase true`) and TortoiseGit will automatically rebase changes on top of your current branch when you pull changes (using the pull dialog or select "Fetch&Rebase" on the Sync dialog). If there is no conflict or the pulled changes fast-forward on top of your current branch, you also won't need to click on "Start rebase" and won't see the rebase dialog.

Another option is already mentioned by [enorl76](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20529703/3906760): Enable "Launch Rebase after fetch" on fetch or pull dialog. Starting with TortoiseGit 1.8.16 you are asked whether you want to open the rebase dialog if the pulled changes fast-forward on top of your current branch or if there are no new commits.

[image: TortoiseGit fetch dialog highlighting Launch-Rebase-After-Fetch checkbox]

Answer (score 8):

You might be able to use the Git Sync (its basically a Swiss army knife for git). It then has an option called Fetch&Rebase which is a drop down from the "Pull" item. If you switch it by default going forward it will be that option. Really cool utility I just ignored it till like 5 minutes ago. Thanks for the other answer cause it helped me find this better answer.